# Using Python PIL to display image sequence in CTKFrame efficiently

Tags: python, image, animation, customtkinter

I am running into a problem displaying an image sequence in a customtkinter frame. The main problem is how inefficient it is to save the images and then display them.  Is there a more efficient way to paste two images and show them without saving them to disk and then displaying in a CTKframe.

I tried using image.show like this customtkinter.CTkImage(img1.show()) however, that pops up a new window and not in the ctkframe.  Here is the code for pasting two images together saving to disk and displaying in CTKframe.

```
cur_img = "img.png"
bground = "bground.png"
# need to save the image to the temp file in order to display in CTK 
img1 = Image.open(os.path.join(self.image_path, bground))
img2 = Image.open(os.path.join(self.sprite_path, cur_img))
img1.paste(img2, img2)
img1.save(new_temp, "PNG")

self.preview_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(new_temp), size=(960, 540))
self.preview_image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_dashboard, text="", image=self.preview_image)
self.preview_image_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
```

For the animation, I have a loop that works but is very slow. I basically open up each file in a folder, paste it to the bground, save to a temp file, and then display it in the frame but that is to slow for an animation.  I would like to just paste and then show in the ctkframe. If this is a limitation of Pillow or customtkinter I am open to using other libraries or even moving to a flask app.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I know that I can paste all the images, save them, and when all the saves are done you can display the sequence, but I am trying to avoid that as it still causes a 30 - 40 second pause before you can continue and disrupts the flow of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think I may have the solution.  I am currently testing and this may have been obvious to everyone else, but instead of pasting img1 and img2 together I need set img1 as the canvas, and can then just display image img2 on top of that.  I will post the solution after some testing.  Kudos to Mark Setchell as his bufferIO definitely sped up my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is insufficient to see what you are really doing and I don't use `tkinter` or its custom variants, however there may be a couple of ways of making things faster:

- firstly, writing PNGs is slow, so maybe you can get away with a (faster) JPEG if you don't need transparency or lossless, and
- secondly, maybe you can write to a memory buffer instead of disk, like this...

---

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create dummy blue PIL Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (320,240), 'blue')

# Create in-memory JPEG
buffer = BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
```

Now you can hopefully use the in-memory JPEG with `tkinter`

```
self.preview_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(buffer, size=(960, 540))
```

Or maybe you need to pass `buffer.getvalue()` instead of `buffer` - like I said, I don't use `tkinter` so give both methods a try.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Unfortunately I need transparency.  But I can definitely try the buffer idea.  Because you asked, my son is interested in programming and I am trying to help as best I can.  We had an idea to make a choose your own adventure style novel / game.  So as options come up it would take a transparent series of PNGs paste them to a background and display that based upon your selection.  I have seen this done in renpy, but I am trying to help my son learn python.  I may be in over my head but we are having fun learning